Do not save changes made in DevTools (F12) to file
I have an MVC site running locally, and I'm using Visual Studio as my main IDE, including for editing CSS files. I have the local site pulled up in Edge and have DevTools (F12) open.
I want CSS file (and JavaScript file) changes made in Visual Studio to be picked up in DevTools as soon as the file is changed - without having to refresh the page or start/stop debugging in Visual Studio. This currently works for me (most of the time) - in the Sources tab, this shows as a green dot over the file name in the left-most panel and on the tab handle, if the file is open in the Sources panel.
When I make changes in the "Styles" section on the Elements tab (for example, checking and unchecking a width: 100% or using the eyedropper to pick background color), I do not want it to make those changes to the actual CSS file(s). My workflow for years has been to use DevTools to test out changes or to see what CSS rule is causing some display issue. Once I figure it out, I make the changes in my main editor (Visual Studio).
But currently, DevTools is saving those changes to file - which at best prompts me when I switch back to Visual Studio with "this file has been changed externally, do you want to reload?", and at worst it makes changes to files that I'm not even realizing it's changing.
Years ago, I found a setting in the DevTools setting where you could turn this off. But it's started saving these changes again, and I cannot find the setting to turn it off now.
I've found some answers that say it's the "Enable Local Overrides" setting that should be disabled, but mine is unchecked. And most other possible answers I've seen around come from 5+ years ago, and the settings available now are not the same as they were then.
I'm currently using Edge version 124.

As far as I know this behavior is not the default, it has to be turned on explicitly -- check to see if you have a local workspace defined in Edge.

Remove the folder in Devtools -> Sources -> Workspace (on the left).

@wOxxOm when I do that, it stops syncing changes the other way too - changes made in Visual Studio aren't reflected as soon as I save the file.

That's how devtools works now. Years ago devtools didn't have the two-way sync. Try changing "Sync CSS changes in the Styles pane" in devtools preferences -> Experiments.

No matter whether I have that checked or unchecked, the behavior is the same.

Please check if you have enabled and used "local override" function. As far as I understand, local override makes changes in the developer tools and saves these changes to the specified file. So, you can navigate to the "Overrides" section of the "Source" panel to check the relevant files. You also can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/sources/#using-the-overrides-tab-to-override-server-files-with-local-files

From my original question: "I've found some answers that say it's the 'Enable Local Overrides' setting that should be disabled, but mine is unchecked." I also have nothing in the "Overrides" section of the "Source" panel.

This "local override" is not a setting, so there is no check or uncheck. You should check whether you have manually deployed anything related to "Override content". If there is, you can try to delete it.
